# Insert additional data in joining table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm building an application with express and i'm using bookshelf (mysql) js as ORM.
I have a relation many-to-many and i'm trying to store in the joining table some additional data.

My models:

```
const Product = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'products',
    factors() {
        return this.belongsToMany('Factor', 'product_factors', 'product_id', 'factor_id')
    }
}) 


const Factor = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'factors',
    products() {
        return this.belongsToMany('Product')
    }

})
```

Creating new product with relations in 'product_factors' table.

```
    /** Create product */
    router.route('/').post((req, res) => {
        new Product({name: req.body.name})
            .save()
            .then(product => {
            // attaching relation
                product.factors().attach([3, 5])
                    .then(hz => {
                        res.status(201).json({
                            message: 'Product created'
                        })
                    })
            })

    })
```

The 'product_factors' table

```
|ID|product_id|factor_id|quantity|
|--|----------|---------|--------|
|1 |10        |3        |NULL    |
|2 |10        |5        |NULL    |
```

How can i insert quantity at the same time with attaching relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has an example of how to do that in [the `model.belongsToMany()` section](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-belongsToMany). For convenience here it is:

```
let Doctor = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  patients: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Patient).through(Appointment);
  }
});

let Appointment = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  patient: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Patient);
  },
  doctor: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Doctor);
  }
});

let Patient = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  doctors: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Doctor).through(Appointment);
  }
});
```

As you can see in the `Doctor` and `Patient` models you must use the `.belongsToMany(Model).through(AnotherModel)`. Then it's just a matter of using the [`attach()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-attach), [`detach()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-detach), [`updatePivot()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-updatePivot) and [`withPivot()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-withPivot) methods as needed to handle the data.

Also, since you're defining the joining model you can also use it directly to access and modify the data that related table contains. For example:

```
Appointment.forge({patient_id: 2, doctor_id: 1, confirmed: true}).save()
```

or

```
Appointment.forge({id: 4}).destroy()
```